# Errno 2 - Django - File Path

Tags: python, django, file, django-views

[image: Here is a picture of what is currently happening to me.]

I am trying to write to a file named data.txt which is within my templates directory, but it is saying '[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'schedule_app/text_files/data.txt''. Any suggestions? I am trying to update a text file based off of query strings. I was only using f.write('hello') to test if it was currently working.

Comment: what do you set in template_directory in your setting.py

Comment: I currently do not have it set to anything. What should it be set to and why must I set it?

Answer (score 0):

Django searches for the template so you don't need to provide the full path.
assuming you are starting your server from the `projectberry` directory then to open the file you would need to use the path `schedule_app/templates/schedule_app/text_files`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set templates directory in your settings.py

See this - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/overriding-templates/#overriding-from-the-project-s-templates-directory